# Changing the shape of a pymunk/Chipmunk physics body

Tags: python, chipmunk, pymunk

I am just getting started with pymunk, and I have a problem that I wasn't able to find a solution to in the documentation.

I have a character body that changes shape during a specific animation.  I know how to attach shapes to a physics body, but how do I change them?  Specifically, I need to change the box to a smaller one temporarily.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of unsafe methods to modify a shape. Right now (v3.0) pymunk only supports updates of the Circle shape and the Segment shapes. However, I just committed a method to update the Poly shape as well, available in latest trunk of pymunk.

If you dont want to run latest trunk I suggest you instead just replace the shape instead of modifying it. The end result will be the same anyway.

(The reason why modification of shapes is discouraged is that its very hard to do a good simulation, the resize happen magically in one instant. For example, how should a collision between of a small object that after a resize would lie inside a large object be resolved?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've done as you said and simply destroyed the old shape and created a new one in its place.  I look forward to seeing a true update method.  By replacing shapes, it forces the programmer to also replace references that may exist elsewhere and is annoying, and wouldn't be an issues if the reference to the new shape stayed the same.

Comment: Would it be possible to have animated shape features though? I would expect that isn't much different from moving objects. (Edit: I would like to use this to simulate the multiplication and growth of (biological) cells.)

Comment: In recent versions of Pymunk all 3 shapes have unsafe set methods that can be used to modify their shapes. Currently there's no built in animation, but you can of course do it "manually". (e.g. increase the radius of a circle by 0.1 each time step for 10 seconds). Should be fairly straight forward to do.